# Setup model response with relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I use Laravel 4.2. I have the following code:

`LogMessage` model:

```
class LogMessage extends Eloquent {
    public function type() {
        return $this->belongsTo('LogMessageType');
    }
}
```

Simple route:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return LogMessage::take(1)->with('type')->get(); 
});
```

Response is like the following:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "192.168.0.100",
    "ts": "2015-11-11 12:22:58",
    "info": "some info",
    "type": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "login"
    }
  }
]
```

Everything is fine, but I need response like this:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "192.168.0.100",
    "ts": "2015-11-11 12:22:58",
    "info": "some info",
    "type": "login"
  }
]
```

I need to load only `name` attribute from `LogMessageType` model  and paste it into `LogMessage`'s `type` attribute.

I'm a newbie in Laravel. What I have to do? Any advice, thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in ORM method for this. The two ways to access it are to either chain it when you want to access it:

```
$logMessage->type->name
```

or manually build the array response you want. If based strictly on your example, there will be a weird functionality issue since you won't want to overwrite the 'type' relationship with a scalar value. An adjustment has been made below:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    $message_response = LogMessage::first();
    $message_response->type_name = $message_response->type->name;
    return $message_response;
});
```

This is essentially the same as the first example but is closer to your desired output. If you are dealing with a Collection rather than an single Eloquent model, then you will need to use get() and a foreach() to build your response Collection/array:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    $message_response = new Collection; // or Array;
    $messages = LogMessage::with('type')->get();
    foreach ($messages as $message)
    {
        $message->type_name = $messages->type->name;
        // you can also completely build your response array from scratch here if you wish
        $message_response->add($message);
    }
    return $message_response;
});
```

Comment: `There is no built-in ORM method for this.` - that is I needed. I already tried this way, but I assumed there is a better, more "clear" way to solve my issue. Thanks!